# Dashing-JS "Hello World" Demo

Tags: javascript, node.js, dashing

I am attempting to work with [Dashing-JS](https://github.com/fabiocaseri/dashing-js), a port of a Sinatra based framework project in Ruby, [Dashing.IO](http://dashing.io/), to Javascript/Node. Essentially I have the core packages and dependencies for Dashing-JS configured; however, when attempting to run just the sample, I am unable to display anything other than this 404 error rather than a sample dashboard: 
[image: Webpage 404 error]

NodeJS CLI output is as follows:
[image: NodeJS CLI]

The project is not well maintained; however, I am curious if an expert in Node might be able to shed some light on the situation. Is a path reference incorrect?

Notes:
1. server.js is referencing sample.jade.

```
 var dashing = require('new-dashing-js').Dashing();

// Set your auth token here
//dashing.auth_token = 'YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN';

/*
dashing.protected = function(req, res, next) {
  // Put any authentication code you want in here.
  // This method is run before accessing any resource.
  // if (true) next();
}
*/

// Set your default dashboard here
dashing.default_dashboard = 'sample';

dashing.start();
```

2. "Sample.jade" is located within the "dashboards" directory

Comment: what URL are you opening?

Comment: It looks like you're attempting to open http://localhost:3030/sample - have you tried http://localhost:3030 instead?

Comment: The line "dashing.default_dashboard = 'sample'; in server.js determines the re-direct. Opening localhost:3030 will automatically redirect to localhost:3030/sample. I agree the issue is here, but I am not sure what I am missing.